# If puppet agent is down, what actions master will do?

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet.

If puppet agent is down, what actions master will do. Is there any way master can listen heartbeat of agent and send an alert if agent is down?

thanks,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no the function puppet master can push action to puppet client like that way.

If you need check puppet agent service health, recommend to install monitoring services, such as `Nagios/Zabbix/Dynatrace` etc, to detect the agent health automatically, and send alert automatically if required.

Another way to monitoring puppet health is, install `Foreman`, it will report health in whole puppet environment, include puppet master server itself.

Comment: Thanks for the informaiton

Comment: Thanks for the updates, @chaitanya Phani. You need vote up if you think that answer helps you, if you think that resolves your problem, you need accept it.